# Yii2 Advance theme integration for frontend and backend

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have installed a yii2 advanced setup and wanted to setup themes for frontend and backend. i have already checked yii official website but unable to find proper tutorial. Please someone help me to resolve it.

Comment: What is your current code, what have you tried?

Comment: you refer this link.... http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

> search **doingiteasy** in youtube have great video tutorial in yii2
>
> [yii2 forum community](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/)
>
> [yii2 tutorial Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html)
>
> [pdf yii2 tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CFMQFjAIahUKEwic4oLd45TIAhVnpXIKHZTjCss&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxn-----8kcagmhdbwcfthzc0aadtq7cdj.xn--p1ai%2Fpublicfiles%2FFileDropZone%2F0%2Fyiiframework1%2F185b70a4b63165357d40701067c08aea.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGJ6Kx09TeN9PMlZc3f1S5M7l9iQA&bvm=bv.103388427,d.bGQ&cad=rja)

and you can also use stack over flow!!!!

**Updated Part:**

[image: view folder that every folder have their controller]
[image: web folder that html assets thier]

> as my perspective the frontend is for your application 
>   and backend is for your admin panel
>   and common part it's the part that is share between those!!!

Comment: i have already checked it, they are customizing current theme, but i want to implement layout theme wise. I want to 2-3 themes and all the related files should be in their folders. In Yii 1 there was theme folder at the root

Comment: checkout the updated part! you should take a part your theme!

Comment: @ Mohsen, 
i wanted to implement theme as i did in yii 1.1, in then all the supported files were in themes folder only. here we have to seprate all the files.

Comment: @Alankar this what you want [yii2 themeing ](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html)   please rate up answer!!